# Live video broadcasting feed

Tags: youtube-api

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a restricted access channel/group where there's a live feed video broadcasting of sport events. The channel/group access is paid by view count to the online host broadcasting website and the copyrights holder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
<mean: price
```

I don't quite understand exactly the payment mechanism in your app. Anyway these are the ways to restrict access:

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html